# Performance millions of files in container Azure blobstorage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

It is bad to store a lot (millions) of files in one folder on NTFS. You can read why in this article: [NTFS performance and large volumes of files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories).

I am storing images for my websites in Azure blob storage. Is it also bad for performance here to store them in one container in the root? Or does creating virtual folders improve performance?

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158452/is-it-better-to-have-many-small-azure-storage-blob-containers-each-with-some-bl?rq=1

Comment: If your issue has been solved, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoyWang I did. But since my answer was so short Stackoverflow converted it to a comment