# Cannot create multiple containers in storage account

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-account

Cannot create multiple containers in storage account due to permission issue.

Please help me to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share more details about `why it is not recommended to do so ?`? You should be able to create multiple containers in a storage account.

Comment: You included the tag `azure-container-registry`. That makes me wonder. Are you referring to blob containers or "compute" containers in your question?

Comment: I am referring to the blob storage.

Comment: Creating a container and sharing to people from different background. It is related to grant permission to access our container ? Different container has different purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any difference between creating large number of containers or fewer containers with more blobs. In fact they can be of advantage of  creating additional security boundaries (like public anonymous access or different SAS signatures for instance or private access) when having more organized created containers. So it has more to do with access control or total storage size. Differentiation of containers can also make it easier to recognize and also when deleting a single container.
You can keep some containers with specific blobs more secure if you want by changing access level to only read access or private access.

[image]

Partitioning in Azure blobs storage is done at the blob level, not the container level .so scalability/parallelization doesn’t effect .

**References:**

1. [azure storage abstractions and their scalability
   targets.html(technet2.github.io/Wiki/blogs)](https://technet2.github.io/Wiki/blogs/windowsazurestorage/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets.html#:%7E:text=An%20account%20can%20have%20many%20Blob%20Containers)
2. [many small Azure storage blob containers
   with some blobs or one really large container -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158452/is-it-better-to-have-many-small-azure-storage-blob-containers-each-with-some-bl)